# Computed value on multipage Webform

Tags: webforms, forms

I have multipage webform. I want to compute the value of the component (Hidden -type) which is on the second page based on the data submitted on the first page.

I'm using `hook_form_alter` and added my `client_submit` handler:

```php
function mymodule_client_submit(&$form, &$form_state)
```

I can read there submitted data from the first page and I can do the calculation. But I cannot set the value of the component from the second page. I can see the structure of the form in `$form` or `$form_state` parameter. But I do not know how to set the value of the component from the second page as it was not submitted yet.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you a simple way to do this. You can pass the calculated value stored in a variable to the next `form` function.

Like I had two step form & at first step of the form user select some name from given name(checkboxes), I store them in array & pass them to the next form function like --

```
function MYMODULE_form($names)//Use your module name instead of MYMODULE.
{
  $return_form = drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_get_form', $names);
  return drupal_render($return_form);
}
function MYMODULE_get_form($form, &$form_state, $names)
{
  $form = array();
  $i = 0;
  foreach($names as $name)
  {
    $form['item']['name'.$i] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#value' => $name,
    );
    $i++;
  }
}
```

Try something like this, if it solves your problem. Use simple variable if you don't have multiple values.

Comment: You can use hook_form with passing your own variable too. Here MYMODULE_form is the function which will be called in next step of your form.

Comment: I tried your code, but it's not working: any markup fields are rendered on the second page.

Comment: I found the `function MYMODULE_form($names)` is not called. Even I use function signature like `function MYMODULE_form($form_id, &$form_state)` it is not called.

Comment: @PetrFelzmann - Paste your full code somewhere & link it here..

Comment: I created module called mt_booking and inside mt_booking.module file I have this code:
    `<?php
    function mt_booking_form($names) {
        drupal_set_message('foobar');
    }
    ?>`
No message is displayed.